# How to dynamically find user based on client's inputs?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to provide a more dynamic way of finding if a Person exist based on the user's input. I'm really just looking for dynamic way based on this silly example:

input fields example

```
let inputField = [
{
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 25,
  married: true
  best_contact: 'email'
},
{
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 24,
  married: false,
  best_contact: 'email'
},
{
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 39,
  married: false,
  best_contact: 'phone'
}
]
```

user's input example

```
let user = {
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 39,
  married: false,
  best_contact: 'email'
}
```

my file...

```
// this is what i have so far

inputField.map(input => {
  return input.find(person => {
    let userKeys = Object.keys(user);
    let result = userKeys.reduce((a, v)) => {
      if(v && person.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
        if(v && input[v] === person[v]) a++;

        else if(['phone', 'email', 'in-person'].includes(v) && person[v]) a++;

        // age condition here i will leave out
      }
     return a;
    }
    return result === userKeys.length; // returns the inputField obj regardless matches users input value
  }
}
// this should return false or nothing
```

In this case, it SHOULD return nothing because the married values do not match. I am getting a match regardless and I'm sure our community here has a much much cleaner, dynamic solution for this. I could specify name, age, married, best_contact in its down condition but i would like a simplier way to do this.

Comment: "*example DB user*" - does that mean you're storing the user objects in a database?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve... Do you want to filter users based on exact match of all fields? What's up with the `userForm()` function? Does it expect boolean fields?

Comment: @Bergi lets say im trying to do a Get request so im trying to find and match if a user exist in the DB. i suppose 'example DB user' is more like a schema we can say

Comment: In that case, you don't need a javascript search algorithm at all. Instead, your API for the GET request should offer url parameters, and dynamically build a query for the database (using the appropriate query language, e.g. SQL).

Comment: @x1n13y84issmd42 I can see how this can be a bit confusing. I'm not trying to filter because this would return multiple results. The userForm() function checks for the values and says true, this has been answered. The end result is yes, it should find, not filter, based on exact match of all fields. it's all or none. if 1 doesnt match, return empty object or 0 or whatever.

Comment: @Bergi yeah i tried to reframe from saying GET... i understand you can hit the API get /:id or whatever. however, i am trying to do this as a javascript without a query, raw javascript. lets just say you have an object and you want to screen if this object matches a your object. what would you do

Comment: Question Rephrased

Comment: `inputField.map(input => { return input.find(person => {` makes it look like `inputField` was a twodimensional array? Don't you just want `input.filter(…)`?

Comment: What should happen if the `user` (search object) and the objects in the `input` array do not have the same properties?

Comment: @Bergi filter returns more than 1 result. find return exactly 1. It's all or none properties. if all but 1 doesnt match, got to return false

Comment: @Invisible-coder Sorry, I meant `inputField.filter(…)`. The example code you posted doesn't work (*`Uncaught TypeError: input.find is not a function`*) even after fixing the syntax errors. Can you post a valid code example please?

Comment: @Invisible-coder well, I'm still not exactly sure what you're after, but [here's my take](https://jsfiddle.net/m840kjc7/).

Comment: @x1n13y84issmd42 this is excellent. Thank you very much!